# How go get value from Route Parameters and save it in Data in Nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

For Example I have this

```
  mounted () {
    this.$router.push({
      path: '/activatewithphone',
      query: { serial: this.$route.params.serial, machine: this.$route.params.machine }
    })
  },
```

This means whenever a user visits a URL like this

```
  http://example.com/activate?serial=sddsdsds&machine=sdsdsd
```

The user will not be shown a 404 page.

The value of serial and machine is dynamic and can be anything.

My question is there a way to take the values and store its data on mounted

e.g

```
  data: () => {
    return {
      serial: '',
      email: '',
    }
  },
```

Can I take the value and assign it to a my serial and email variables, maybe using `this.serial`

Comment: Use computed or created hook and then assign the value using `this.serial = this.$routes.params.serial`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `computed property`:

```js
computed: {
  serial() {
    return this.$route.query.serial
  },
  email() {
    return this.$route.query.email
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but somehow it shows me the values are undefined.

Comment: If user open ` http://example.com/activate?email=sometext`  there is no `serial` value so it would be `undefined` and you can set initial value for serial like this: `return this.$route.query.serial || 'DEFAULT_SERIAL_VALUE'`

Comment: example.comn/activatewithphone?serial=sddsdsds&email=sdsdsd
both serial and email are undefined. 

The thing is when a user visit `example.com/activatewithphone?serial=sddsdsds&email=sdsdsd`, it clear the parameters and show `example.com/activatewithphone`